# necessary and sufficient condition that $f$ (X\A) $\subset$ Y\ $f$(A)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$f$: X $\rightarrow$ Y , A necessary and sufficient condition that $f$ (X\A) $\subset$ Y\ $f$(A) for all subsets A to X is that $f$ is injective.

I know that there are two statements, one of which i have to prove while i assume the other is correct, and vice versa. What is throwing me of is how to begin to connect $f$ (X\A)  with  Y\ $f$(A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f(X\setminus A) \subset Y\setminus f(A)$ for all $A$. Let $x \neq y$ and take $A=\{x\}$. Then $f(x) \in f(A)$ and $f(y) \in f(X\setminus A) \subset Y\setminus f(A)$. So we cannot have $f(x)=f(y)$. This proves that $f$ is injective. Converse part is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f$ is injective.

Suppose that there is some subset $A$ of $X$ such that $f(X \setminus A)$ is not a subset of $Y \setminus f(A)$. Hence there is $x \in X \setminus A$ with $f(x)  \in f(A)$. Thus we have $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $y \in A$. Since $f$ is injective, we get $x=y$, hence $x \in A$, a contradiction.

It is now your turn to prove that $f$ is injective, if $f (X \setminus A) ⊂ Y \setminus f(A)$ for all subsets A of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be any set and let $b \in f(X \setminus A)$. Then $\exists \, s \in X \setminus A$ such that $f(s)=b$.

Assuming that $f$ is injective, there is no other input (apart from $s$) in $X$ which maps to $b$. In particular, we have that $\forall \, a \in A, \,\, f(a) \neq b$. In other words, $b \not\in f(A)$. Said differently, $b \in Y \setminus f(A)$.

Can you now do the other implication?